# SQL: using max/min aggregate functions with associated record

Tags: sql, sap-iq

```
+-------------------------+
| id  date value comments |
+-------------------------+
| 1   d1    10    c1      |
| 1   d2    20    c2      |
| 1   d3    30    c3      |
| 2   d7    70    c4      |
+-------------------------+
```

Want to write an SQL to create flatten out table that looks like following:

id | max_value | date_of_max_value | min_value | date_of_min_value

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support window functions, such as `row_number()`.  This let's you solve this problem using conditional aggregation:

```
select id, max(value) as max_value,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then date end) as date_max_value,
       min(value) as min_value,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then date end) as date_min_value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by value asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by value desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please explain why you had to encapsulate "case when seqnum_desc = 1 then date end" in max and min? I was looking for just the date corresponding to max value and min value respectively? your help is appreciated.

Comment: @toing . . . This is how conditional aggregation works.  Those expressions are pulling the value of `date` where `value` is maximum or minimum.

Comment: Thanks. I looked up a bit. I think whats throwing me off is use of "max" on the conditional aggregation of date. Would this be same if i were to get field "comments" corresponding to max or min value? would you still use something like max( case when seqnum_desc = 1 then comments end )? what if i were to swap max with min?

Comment: @toing . . . The `max()` could be `min()` as well.  The `case` only chooses one record.